# How to access space separated property in Neo4j using Java

Tags: java, neo4j, graph-databases

I'm creating a graph DB of Taxis network storing in each node a taxi with a long list of properties of (date, fee), I'm storing a date in Java 
`DATE` format that contains spaces but I cannot access it while matching.

```
MATCH (t) WHERE t.name='someTaxi' RETURN t.Sun Mar 01 00:00:00 EET 2015;
```

But this didn't work so I used backtick-ing

**I stored property key with backticks like this 'Sun Mar 01 00:00:00 EET 2015' the second time**

```
MATCH (t) WHERE t.name='someTaxi' RETURN t.'Sun Mar 01 00:00:00 EET 2015';
```

but this didn't work either.

So Is it possible to store a property key like that in **Neo4j** and How can I return it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The problem

You are storing some data this way (json representation):

`{name: "someTaxi", Sun Mar 01 00:00:00 EET 2015 : fees}`

This data model is bad, considering Neo'j's ability to manage such datas using relations.

### The solution

You have to create a better data model using Neo4j's power: Relations. Here is an example of what you wan do:
[image: Graph Example]

Here is the node details (pseudo cypher representation):

`(:Taxi{name:someTaxi})-[:EARNED{date:<Here you set your date>}]->(:Fees{value:<The amount>)`

So now, to match your fees, you can simply use this query:

```
MATCH (t:Taxi{name : <taxi Name>})-[r:EARNED{date: <yourDate>}]->(f:Fees) 
RETURN f.value
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I need to store the property keys as a (Date, fee) cause when I select from this DB I'll need to retrieve the fees that this taxi earned at a particular set of dates.
I'll have to set a property for each 15 min of each day for a full year which is 35040 property for a single taxi and I have about 100 taxi per city network, so doubling the number of properties will be gigantic on the long run.

Comment: Wow, your data model is wrong then, it's a bad idea to retreive a set of data this way, first of all because you'll have 35040 property per node, which is bad, and you are using the property name to store some data. I'll edit the answer to show you how to do this using a better data model.